# Vue bootstrap b-form-select sets vuelidate's $anyDirty to true on load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

The issue I'm having is due to the `input` event that's being run when I first set a value to the `v-model`, this data is being loaded in via an API; I understand why the form is being set to dirty (as this it is being changed) but this causes problems in another component I have which checks if the [`$v.$anyDirty`](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/#sub-v-values) flag is sets to true and if it is, creates a pop up to say "are you sure you want to navigate away" but calling [`$v.reset()`](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/#sub-v-methods) after the data is loaded doesn't work.

```js
Vue.use(vuelidate.default);
const { required } = window.validators;
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [],
    todo: ""
  },
  async created() {
    var data = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
    this.todos = data.data.map(d => d.id);
    this.todo = this.todos[0];
    this.$v.$reset()
  },
  validations() {
    return {
      todo: { required }
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate@0.7.4/dist/validators.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate@0.7.4/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>



<div id='app'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <b-form-select v-model="$v.todo.$model" :options="todos"></b-form-select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <code>
        $anyDirty: {{$v.$anyDirty}}
      </code>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$v.reset()` is being run before vue renders so the input events happen after, so the stack trace would look like this

> load > set values > reset validation > render > input event

You need to put the reset inside [`Vue.nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) and then it'll work as it'll change the execution to be

> load > set values > render > input event > reset validation

```js
Vue.use(vuelidate.default);
const {
  required
} = window.validators;
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [],
    todo: ""
  },
  async created() {
    var data = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
    this.todos = data.data.map(d => d.id);
    this.todo = this.todos[0];
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      this.$v.$reset()
    })
  },
  validations() {
    return {
      todo: {
        required
      }
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate@0.7.4/dist/validators.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate@0.7.4/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>



<div id='app'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <b-form-select v-model="$v.todo.$model" :options="todos"></b-form-select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <code>
        $anyDirty: {{$v.$anyDirty}}
      </code>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a note, you can also call [`Vue.nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) with `this.$nextTick`